# Convert DATETIME format to custom format in bigquery

Tags: sql, python-2.7, google-bigquery

I have a column in `BigQuery` in `DATETIME` eg `2018-08-16T11:00:35.683000` which I would like to convert in some custom format which is `YYYY-MM-dd HH:MM`.
How can I do this ?
I am getting below error while converting:

> ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform localtime()/gmtime() function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATETIME '2018-08-16T11:00:35.683000' dt
)
SELECT FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %R', dt) cust_dt
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row cust_dt  
1   2018-08-16 11:00
```

Comment: @Neha0908, you can find more information here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#format_datetime :)